# Normalized "probability functions" such that the marginal are not probability functions

Tags: probability-theory, physics, mathematical-physics

This question is inspired from Quantum Optics. There one has a nonnegative normalized function, "Husimi function" such that

$$
\int\int dx dp Q(x,p) = 1,
$$

where the integrals are done over the whole complex plane. However, in the literature it is insisted time and again that this is only a quasi-distribution, in the sense that the marginals are not obtained from it, e.g.

$$
\int dp Q(x,p) \neq P(x),
$$

where $P(x)$ is the probability function over the $x$-axis. However, it might be that $\int dp Q(x,p)= R(x) $ such that $\int R(x)=1$, positive definite and at the end $R(x)$ "resembles" a probability density function in its own right.

With this $R(x)$, is it still possible to say that $Q(x,p)$ is a probability function instead of a "quasi-probability"? Does it exist a probability function $Q'(x,p)$ nonnegative and normalized to one such that $\int dp Q'(x,p) = R'(x)$ but $\int R(x)\neq 1$?

Comment: Clear, I simply forgot to mark it after the couple of days :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help you to refer to [this PSE question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/375157/proof-of-non-existence-of-marginals-of-the-husimi-q-function) and its answer. Your texts *should* have emphasized *why* all these phase-space distributions, semi-definite-positive or not,
cannot be probability distributions.

The reason is they all fail [Kolmogorov's third axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms#Third_axiom) that different points of the plane represent mutually exclusive logical alternatives, which, you might know from physics, contiguous points within an $\hbar$ distance do *not*, by dint of the uncertainty principle.

The positive semi-definiteness itself of *Q* is a red herring, ritually confusing the novice. Suppose one has a function *f(x)*, whose expectation value one wishes to find. Your texts *should* have described *why*
$$
\langle f(x)\rangle \neq \int\int\!\!dpdx ~ Q(x,p) f(x) = \int\!\! dx ~  R(x) f(x). 
$$

The easiest way to see this is to refer *Q* to the Wigner distribution *W*, (the Cartesian coordinate system of these distributions, so to speak!), whose marginal *is a bona-fide probability distribution P(x)*,
$$
\langle f(x)\rangle = \int\int\!\!dpdx ~ W(x,p) f(x) = \int\!\! dx ~  P(x) f(x). 
$$

You thus utilize the fact that the Hussimi is the [Weierstrass transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_transform) of the Wigner distribution,
$$
 Q(x,p) = \exp \left({ 1\over 4}(\partial_x^2
           +\partial_p^2 ) \right) W(x,p)     \\
 \propto \int \int dx' dp' 
\exp \left( -{(x'-x)^2-(p'-p)^2   } \right) ~ W(x',p') ,
$$
to see that its marginal
$$
\int  \int \int  dp dx' dp' 
\exp \left( -{(x'-x)^2-(p'-p)^2   } \right) ~ W(x',p') ,
$$
is *not* the probability distribution *P(x)* we already saw.

Instead, you'd need something like
$$
\langle f(x)\rangle =  \int\!\!dx ~ \left (\int dp \exp \left(-{ 1\over 4}(\partial_x^2 + \partial_p^2)
              \right)  Q(x,p)\right )~~ f(x) = \int\!\! dx ~  P(x) f(x).
$$

Damning the torpedoes to go full speed ahead, and using plain *Q* s without Weierstrass kernels produces [Wehrl quasi-entropies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wehrl_entropy) , uncontrolled approximants of the von Neumann entropy.

Comment: Thank you, actually I found the answer you suggest yesterday and have rated it already.

Comment: I think the main problem is that the texts and papers only say: the $Q$ function does not fulfill the "marginal property" (MP) and hence it cannot be a PDF, but no one really gives the proof of it. In any case, I made the question here because I thought that for mathematicians would be easy to give a counter example of a nonegative and normalized function such that it does not have the MP (not necessarily $Q$), but yours works fine. I had a rough time trying to convince someone of this.

Comment: The marginals' failure  is an easy reality check when it comes to not getting too attached to the Hussimi. Note if you *did* skip the exponential kernel in the last equation, as you are suggesting, you'd effectively take an uncontrolled semiclassical approximation of the  Wigner function, a low-pass filtering, so you'd sacrifice fine information. People do such things in the context of entropy calculations, on account of technical ease, but, in the last analysis, they are applying an uncontrolled approximation...